# I have radio buttons in react, but users cannot select one of them

Tags: javascript, reactjs, radio-button

I have following code on React in JS. I have 4 radio buttons. But when users try to select one of them, they cannot. What could cause this? When I try to debug the code myself, I see that handleChange function does not wire.

```
import Radio from "@mui/material/Radio"
import RadioGroup from "@mui/material/RadioGroup"
import FormControlLabel from "@mui/material/FormControlLabel"
import FormControl from "@mui/material/FormControl"
import FormLabel from "@mui/material/FormLabel"

  const [value, setValue] = useState("last7d")

  const handleChange = event => {
    setValue(event.target.value)
  }

            <FormControl>
              <FormLabel id="demo-controlled-radio-buttons-group">
                Gender
              </FormLabel>
              <RadioGroup
                row
                aria-labelledby="demo-controlled-radio-buttons-group"
                name="controlled-radio-buttons-group"
                value={value}
                onChange={handleChange}
              >
                <FormControlLabel
                  value="last24h"
                  control={<Radio />}
                  label="Last 24 hours"
                />
                <FormControlLabel
                  value="last7d"
                  control={<Radio />}
                  label="Last 7 days"
                />
                <FormControlLabel
                  value="last30d"
                  control={<Radio />}
                  label="Last 30 days"
                />
                <FormControlLabel
                  value="thismonth"
                  control={<Radio />}
                  label="This Month"
                />
              </RadioGroup>
            </FormControl>
```

Comment: Put your code to a sandbox, so others can play with it

Comment: I put the code into a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/mui-radio-buttons-mg7twq?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A14%2C1), and the issue does not reproduce.  Please update you question with code that reproduces the issue.